# xfce4-terminal: keyboard shortcut to set terminal title

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, xfce

How can one set a keyboard shortcut for an instance of `xfce4-terminal`? It appears that the *Terminal->Set Title* menu does not have a shortcut tooltip, and I would really like to keep my open terminals organized.

Addendum: if this is not possible within `xfce4-terminal` itself, maybe there is a way to do this using an OS shortcut? I am using OpenSuSe 13.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hover over menu item and press desired keyboard combination. To remove one, hover and press <kbd>Backspace</kbd>. **If it doesn't work, see the FAQ for pointers how to enable GTK+ shortcuts changing for you may not have it enabled**. Attached screenshot from the FAQ as well.

From http://docs.xfce.org/faq, quoting here for your convenience:

> A number of Xfce applications (Xfce Terminal and Thunar for example)
>   support the standard GTK+ way of changing shortcuts: simply hover over
>   the menu option with the mouse pointer and press the keyboard shortcut
>   you want to rebind it to.
>
> To delete a keyboard assignment, press the Backspace key while you are
>   on the menu entry.

Just had same problem and found this out, I did that by accident with <kbd>s</kbd> and could not type commands with **s** cause it would ask me for a new terminal title. :D

EDIT after comment:

> if the shortcut doesn't change, then you need to enable the feature in
>   GTK+. This can be achieved in 3 ways:
>
> ```
> If you are running the Xfce desktop environment, enable Editable menu accelerators in the User Interface Preferences dialog.
> If you are running GNOME then you can enable Editable menu accelerators in the Menu and Toolbars control center dialog.
> Otherwise put the following in your ~/.gtkrc-2.0 file (create the file if it doesn't exist):
> gtk-can-change-accels=1
> ```

[image: FAQ screenshot]

Comment: That would be a great solution, however for me it didn't work...

Comment: @Pickle - edited my answer with how to enable that way of changing shortcuts.

Comment: In Xubuntu, to get to the User Interfaces Dialog search for the **Appearances** dialog (at least on version Xfce 4.12)

Answer (score 4):

You can "always" set the terminal title from the command-line, since XFCE4 Terminal uses VTE, which supports the corresponding xterm title escape sequence.  A simple script like this would work (setting both title and icon name):

```
#!/bin/sh
printf '\033]0;%s\007' "$*"
```

OpenSUSE also has `xtermset` available; it sets title or icon, e.g.,

```
xtermset -T "my title"
```

I just checked, to see that the title can be set independently on each tab (though ultimately this is a feature of VTE and can be broken by upgrades if the GNOME developers decide to deprecate it further).

However, if you are using `bash`, its default setting for `PS1` makes it modify the title, and your changes would be lost.

Further reading:

- [Bash Prompt HOWTO: 6.3. Xterm Title Bar Manipulations](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/xterm-title-bar-manipulations.html)
- [How to change the title of the current terminal tab using only the command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/636944/how-to-change-the-title-of-the-current-terminal-tab-using-only-the-command-line)
  some of the problems in this discussion are due to confusion over how the bash prompt *works*.
- [Unable to set gnome-terminal title from menu in 15.04, 15.10, 16.04 LTS, 16.10](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1448511)
  A few years ago, the feature was deprecated.
- [How to change Gnome-Terminal title?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22413/how-to-change-gnome-terminal-title)
  the menu entry *used* to be a feature of GNOME-Terminal as well.

Comment: The printf variant does not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

- Go to `~/.config/xfce4/terminal`
- Open your `~/.config/xfce4/terminal/accels.scm` in an editor.
- You will see a long list with keyboard shortcuts that are only available for `xfce4-terminal`.
- Try to find:

  ```scm
  (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/terminal-window/set-title" "<Primary>F2")
  ```

  this is my setting for `naming` or `renaming` a `tab`.
- In your case, you will find it with a `semicolon` at beginning, meaning that is "commented", like this:

  ```scm
  ;(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/terminal-window/set-title" "<Primary>F2")
  ```
- In order to apply the settings and load them into the terminal everytime, you need to "uncomment".
- Use whatever you want.

  `<Primary>` - CTRL 
  `<Shift>` - SHIFT 
  `<F2>` - F2 
  and so on

  and letters are with lowercase

  `a` - a 
  and so on
- For example, if you want <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, you would have:

  ```
  "<Primary><Shift>a"
  ```

  and you are ready to go.